# What is the difference between returning and not returning a promise inside the then-block of another promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

What exactly is the difference? In the two scenarios below, what type of difference does `myPromise` have?

Here is the example:

#### Case 1. Returning a promise

```
function test() {
  return somePromise.then(() => {
    return anotherPromise.then(res => {
      console.log('Result:', res);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

const myPromise = test();
```

#### Case 2. Not returning a promise

```
function test() {
  return somePromise.then(() => {
    anotherPromise.then(res => {
      console.log('Result:', res);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}

const myPromise = test();
```

Comment: The main difference is that the second one is an antipractice. Fire-and-forget is rarely a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case is **"promise chaining"** and it a very common and useful tool.  By returning a promise from a `.then()` handler, you are telling the parent promise that you want it to wait until the returned promise is done before resolving itself.  This allows you to create a sequence of events and know when the entire sequence is done by monitoring the top level promise.  Anyone watching the parent promise will only see a resolve or reject when the "chained" promise is also resolved or rejected.  Errors from the chained promise will propagate upwards.

Also, the resolved value of the parent promise will become the resolved value of the chained promise.

The second case is just starting a new promise chain that is not connected to the original one in any way.  It won't propagate errors and the parent promise won't wait for it.  It's kind of like a "fire and forget" operation where you're running it separately, but not connecting it at all to the parent operation.

This is usually a "bug" (though there are occasionally situations where you want to start a new async operation and are not reporting its success or failure back to anyone).  In the code you show, if `anotherPromise` rejected, you'd get a warning about an unhandled rejection because it is not chained and will not propagate up to your `.catch()`.

Answer (score 1):

First case will wait until the `anotherPromise` will be *resolved* or *rejected*, then pass the execution to the next `then` of `somePromise` with the *resolved* or *rejected* value of the **`anotherPromise`**. So the chain is made by the values of both `anotherPromise` and `somePromise`.

Second will just run the inner promise, forget about it and return the execution to the next `then` of `somePromise` with the *resolved* or *rejected* value of the **`somePromise`**. So the chain is made by the values of only `somePromise`.

Answer (score 1):

Well for one, the second one's `catch` block would not be hit if there was a problem with the nested promise.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, `myPromise` will not resolve until both `somePromise` and `anotherPromise` have resolved.

In the second case, `myPromise` will resolve as soon as `somePromise` resolves. Additionally, the `catch` handler will not catch any error from `anotherPromise` if it rejects.

The latter is generally an antipractice because it is an example of "fire and forget" code.

Bear in mind that you are also building up a "pyramid of doom" there. A preferable approach to both of those examples would be:

```
function test() {
  return somePromise
    .then(() => anotherPromise)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('Result:', res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

const myPromise = test();
```