# Wait until all subpromises are resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, promise

Let's say I have something like:

```
const exampleFunction = () => {
const fetchActions = someArray.map(() => {
                dispatch(action()).then(response => {
                    if (response?.data) {
                        dispatch(subAction({response: response.data}))
                    }
                })
            })

return Promise.all(fetchActions)
.then(()=> dispatch(finalAction()))
}
```

My problem is that when I dispatch my finalAction, all the actions have been dispatched/resolved but not the subActions. How can I execute my dispatch(finalAction())) ONLY when all the actions and subActions have been resolved?

Comment: Looks like `dispatch` returns a promise, so maybe all you have to do is add a `return`: `return dispatch(action())...` and `return dispatch(subAction(...))`.

Comment: As well as pointed out, you can put `return dispatch...` or alternatively remove the `{}`'s.    `.map() => dispatch(....` and you get the implicit return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `Promise.all([...promises])` resolves when all `promises` resolve but your `fetchActions` is not really an array of promises (that you intended) because they have *orphaned promises* with the promise chain disconnected. In order to connect the chain again, you need to add `return`.

```
const exampleFunction = () => {
  const fetchActions = someArray.map(() => {
    return dispatch(action()).then(response => {
      if (response?.data) {
        return dispatch(subAction({
          response: response.data
        }))
      }
    })
  })

  return Promise.all(fetchActions)
    .then(() => dispatch(finalAction()))
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548987/what-is-the-difference-between-returning-and-not-returning-a-promise-inside-the) to learn more about promise chaining.

---

Basically, the idea is: if you want a function to resolve after the promise called inside it is resolved, you need to `return` that promise.

For example:

```
const promiseA = () => {
  promiseY();
};

const promiseB = () => {
  promiseZ();
};

await Promise.all([promiseA(), promiseB()]);
```

`Promise.all` above immediately resolves without waiting for `promiseY` or `promiseZ` because they're *orphaned promises*.

In order to wait for them, it should be like this:

```
const promiseA = () => {
  return promiseY();
};

const promiseB = () => {
  return promiseZ();
};

await Promise.all([promiseA(), promiseB()]);
```